# AngularJS - img ng-src to base64 data (not url) not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, base64

I'm using [openfb-angular](https://github.com/thaiat/angular-fbopen) (Facebook API library) to get **me/picture**.
The return data is "url" contains Base64 data [here is the facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture).

Here is my code:

**JS**

```
OpenFB.get('/me/picture', {format: 'json'}).success(function (imgData)
        {
            $scope.main.user.imageData = imgData;
        });
```

**HTML**

```
 <img ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{main.user.imageData}}">
```

It's not working and I get an empty `img` tag.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: please paste any sample of imageData. did you checked the format of image you are getting back? is it jpg?
If possible please post code in Plunker.

Like i have a image shown here
http://plnkr.co/edit/m24ZcYuttw6IuCBh02rQ?p=preview

Comment: have you tried to use src only instead of ng-src?

Comment: Is it should be `image/jpeg` instead of `image/jpg`?

Comment: hi @cheziHoyzer, i´m facing this issue right now... have you solved the problem with the image in base64? thx

Answer (score 15):

Use ng-source directive like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{'data:image/png;base64,'+main.user.imageData}}" >
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Use `data-ng-src` directive like this `<img data-ng-src="{{data.image_url}}">`.

In your controller set base64 string as this:
`$scope.data.image_url=<your base64 image source>`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{main.user.imageData}}"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

In Angular 7, this would be:

`<img [src]="'data:image/png;base64,' + main.user.imageData" />`