# Retrieve image from database using Web API, then displaying it in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Seems like a straightforward issue, but how can you retrieve an image stored in a database, using Web API, then display it using Angular?

Here is an example Web API service which is correctly returning a JPG file (using `HttpResponseMessage`):

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetIncidentImages(Guid IncidentIDX) {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        List<T_EM_INCIDENT_ATTACH> att = db_Layer.GetT_EM_INCIDENT_ATTACH_byIncidentIDX(IncidentIDX);
        if (att != null)
        {
            if (att.Count > 0)
            {
                var pictureBytes = att[0].ATTACH_CONTENT;  //ATTACH_CONTENT is a byte array

                if (pictureBytes == null)
                    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                else
                {
                    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pictureBytes);
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
                }
            }
            else
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Then on the http client-side, I am using angular to retrieve the data. Data is definitely getting retrieved, but just not displayed.

```
    dbManagerService.syncIncidentAttach(ehConstants.incidenT_IDX).then(function (res) {
        console.log("return", res);

        $scope.cameraPic = res;
    });

function _syncIncidentAttach(incIDX) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get($rootScope.serverBaseUrl + 'api/incident/GetIncidentImages?IncidentIDX=' + incIDX, { responseType: "blob" })
    .success(function (res, status, headers, config) {
        // encode data to base 64 url
        fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function () {
            // this variable holds your base64 image data URI (string)
            // use readAsBinary() or readAsBinaryString() below to obtain other data types
            console.log(fr.result);
        };
        fr.readAsDataURL(res);

        deferred.resolve(fr);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        conole.log('error getting image');
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

And the html:

```
 <img ng-src="{{cameraPic}}" /> </div>
```

Comment: I sugest you firstly check your scope data tree to see if <img> is put in right scope to display. Best tool to do this is [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your server side code, I think you can directly write like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{serverBaseUrl}}api/incident/GetIncidentImages?IncidentIDX={{ehConstants.incidenT_IDX}}" />
```

Just make sure you are replacing `ehConstants.incidenT_IDX` with actual content.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30264303/4463445), you can also do something like

```
<img ng-src="{{'data:image/png;base64,' + main.user.imageData}}">
```